# ErrorT is deprecated, but ExceptT doesn't fit

Tags: haskell

I had a monadic computation.  At some point it started requiring a MonadFail constraint because of a monadic pattern-match.

My easy fix was to run it with this:

```
fmap (either error id) . runErrorT
```

Yet ouch:

```
Deprecated: "Use Control.Monad.Trans.Except instead"
```

So it appears that `ErrorT` is deprecated, and I'm to use `ExceptT` instead.  That sounds fine from the outside, but it doesn't appear like ExceptT is a drop-in replacement *at all!*  Just look at the instance declarations:

```
instance (Monad m, Error e) => MonadFail (ErrorT e m)
instance MonadFail m => MonadFail (ExceptT e m)
```

`ErrorT` *provides* a MonadFail implementation.  `ExceptT` merely *lifts* it.

I'm not quite sure where to go from this point.

- my code eventually won't have the refutable bind at all.  It's one of those cases where it's statically known to work, yet not proven to the type checker yet.  I'll get there, but it'll take a while.  (Like, I'm going to need dependent types, so I'm going to need to learn dependent types.  It'll take a while.)
- yet in the meantime, my code needs to bind, and really I'm fine with `error` being called if I mess up.

It seems what I'm looking for is some generic `MonadFail` implementation that allows me to… well, do what I want with a pattern failing to match.  `ErrorT` did this, and `ExceptT` doesn't.

What are my non-deprecated options?

Comment: I currently don't have time to write a full answer but if you are fine with `error` you could make the pattern match with an irrefutable pattern match, say if you have `Just foo <- bar` you could instead write `~(Just foo) <- bar`, This relaxes the constraint to `Monad` but results in a runtime error should the match fail. you could also write your own monad transformer to replace `ErrorT`, or use an explicit `case ... of ...` and call `error` on failure, or `throwError` if you use `ExceptT`

Comment: Newtype wrap ExceptT and define your desired MonadFail instance.

Comment: @M.Aroosi drat. I thought I tried that already. Sounds like my perfect least-effort path. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I'm not quite sure why I'd need an ExceptT if I'm to provide a MonadFail instance on my own anyway.

Comment: @boran I'm aware of that question (it was the google match before I asked mine.)  But unless I misread it, it specifically doesn't address what I'm asking for: a default MonadFail instance. The section on do pattern matching failure more or less boils down to “remove pattern match failures”.

Comment: Because building on ExceptT allows you to derive the vast majority of instances you'll probably want.

Comment: Ah, good point. My current intermediate status was this: http://dpaste.com/0SHKHSE and indeed, writing instances was most of the work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question! I even wrote an actual library [`FailT`](https://github.com/lehins/FailT) that solves this problem of graceful failure with `MonadFail`.

I am not sure about what was the exact setup, but I'd like to answer this question with a concrete example. Let's say we have a monadic action that accepts another monadic action that produces `MyType` and we can bet our family farm that it will be the `Expected` case:

```hs
data MyType a = Expected a | Unexpected a
  deriving (Show)

myFunc :: (Show a, MonadFail m) => m (MyType a) -> m String
myFunc t = do
  Expected a <- t
  pure $ show a
```

Unfortunately there is no suitable solution in `base` or other libraries that are wired with GHC, like `transformers` or `mtl` for example.

As you already know `ErrorT` would have worked perfectly for this, but it was deprecated for good reasons.

`ExceptT` could have provided a sensible `MonadFail` instance, but this would have been quite problematic for backwards compatibility.

As it was suggested in the comments wrapping around `ExceptT` with a `newtype` and providing a custom `MonadFail` instance would certainly work, but who wants to include it in their codebase every time they run into this issue. For completeness sake here is a minimal self contained solution:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

newtype ResultT m a = ResultT (ExceptT String m a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance Monad m => MonadFail (ResultT m) where
  fail = ResultT . throwE

runResultT :: ResultT m a -> m (Either String a)
runResultT (ResultT m) = runExceptT m
```

Naturally, many more instances can be derived, but not all of them. `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` have ugly behavior.

One way or another, this is a common enough problem to have a proper reusable solution for. This is how it can be handled using the [`FailT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/FailT-0.1.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Fail-String.html#t:FailT) monad transformer:

```hs
λ> import Control.Monad.Trans.Fail.String (runFailT)
λ> runFailT (myFunc (pure (Expected "Totally fine")))
Right "\"Totally fine\""
λ> runFailT (myFunc (pure (Unexpected "Surprise!")))
Left "Pattern match failure in 'do' block at /home/lehins/github/public/haskell/stackoverflow/errort-is-deprecated-but-exceptt-doesnt-fit/src/Lib.hs:25:3-12"
```

For anyone interested in more detail on this topic I also wrote a whole blog post about it: [Fail with class](https://alexey.kuleshevi.ch/blog/2023/01/16/fail-with-class/).